# Sharepoint 2010 CSS - Quick Way to Clear all old template styles?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css, branding

I am a web developer who doesn't typically work with SharePoint but I was asked to style up an existing site that uses one of the default v4 templates (blue/light blue). I have been changing over the styles but there seems to be a ton of lingering rollovers and other styles still showing up depending on what sort of site it is, etc.

Is there a simple/quick way to zero out the 845,234 default rollovers, bg gradients, rollover borders on webparts, ribbon borders, etc, or is this something that I would need to find manually?

Comment: One of the joys of SP branding. Overriding styles one by one.

Comment: I don't thing there is an easy way to somehow selectively remove certain standard SharePoint styles. You either get them all or none of them. You don't want to remove standard CSS because it's  going to be a titanic job for you. So, you'll have to continue to do what you are already doing.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov I figured this was the case but hoped it would be a bit less time consuming. Seems a bit inefficient to me, but then again, lots of things with SharePoint to be encumbered by inefficiency.

Comment: What about the ReplaceColor feature? Can that be used in a master page or something? I don't have easy access to the /LAYOUTS folder. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In order to overcome the tedium that ensues at the onset of every SharePoint 2010 design project, I have created a simple snippet of CSS that is intended to *reset* the SharePoint interface styles to inherit from your default document styles.

Take a look at the [SharePoint 2010 CSS Reset](http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/css-reset/) from Kyle Schaeffer. I didn't test it yet, but it seems to do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Great find. This is a great idea since it sets you up to inherit from your existing styles.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to style over the existing SharePoint CSS styles, you should create a separate stylesheet if you have not already and in your code reference it like so in the `<head>` tag. You should never modify the corev4.css file.

```
<SharePoint:CSSRegistration ID="CSSRegistration1" name="/_layouts/15/MyStyles/CSS/style.css" After="corev15.css" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Yeah I'm doing all that. My styles show up just fine, it's just all these ridiculous styles in the template. I'm trying to find out if there's a trick like when you reset margins and padding to 0 before doing a "normal" stylesheet. Most of my styles override, but I don't want there to be random blue borders, rollover gradients and :hover/:selected type styles when I go to implement this theme across the site.